# How can load page from server

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I am an asp.net programming and I trying to load page without request to server.
**How I can load page and send parameters without reload the page on browser using asp.net and jquery ?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want [$.load](http://api.jquery.com/load/)

```
$("#target").load("/server/path/to/source.html");
```

Comment: it is working but i need to show this page with parameters in address bar of browser.

Comment: You can maintain only `hash` part of location without page reload. For example `window.location.hash = "page=2&param=aaa"`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a ajax query. Still the request will be sent to server but asynchronously.
So your page will not refresh.

[Here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)'s the jquery ajax function.

```
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: "/AjaxController.aspx",
  dataType: "html",
  success : function(){ 
  $("#div1").html(result);
  }  
});
```

Comment: thank you , your code is clearly to me but while run the code it is give me error (200 parseerror) !!

Comment: dataType should be `html` in your case

Comment: Thanks @Tommi for pointing that out. You should prefer json as response make sure u set the content-type as applicaton\json and use `JSON.parse(result);`